# Amount of English fiction literature in characters / publications

Tags: english, literature

What can be a rough estimate of all the English fiction literature published to date in characters? Or the trends for fiction books published yearly? What can be the public sources for such estimates?

Regarding the second question, I have found [this data](http://www.bowker.com/tools-resources/Bowker-Data.html) helpful. But as the data concerns only the relatively recent publications, it would be not so helpful in providing the answer to the main question.

Comment: Do you mean literature printed on paper and sold in stores? Should literature published only in electronic form (Amazon ebooks, fan-fiction, blog stories, etc) be counted?